# How to open a new browser tab in the same window as the web application from which it is launched

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

From web app 1, hyperlink 1 is clicked to launch web app 2 in a new browser window. Web app 2 is a `Spring Boot`, `Spring MVC` app, which utilises `Thymeleaf Templates`. It displays hyperlink 2, which when clicked, opens a file for viewing in a new tab using _blank as the target This works fine, but the new tab is launched in the same window as app 1, which is a little confusing for the user. Ideally, the file should open in a new tab within the same window as app 2.

This is the code for hyperlink 2:

```
<a th:text="${'object_name'}"
   th:href="@{/content/{filename}(filename=${'object_name')})}"
   target="_blank">
</a>
```

My first attempt at a fix is pasted below. The behaviour remains unchanged:

```
<a th:text="${'object_name'}"
   th:href="@{/content/{filename}(filename=${'object_name')})}"
   onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;">
</a>
```

My second attempt at a fix is pasted below. The file now opens in the same Window as app 2, but unfortunately it does not open a new tab, it just replaces app 2 in the existing tab:

```
<a th:text="${'object_name'}"
   th:href="@{/content/{filename}(filename=${'object_name')})}"
   onclick="openInSameWindow(event)">
</a>
```

Function added to my JavaScript file:

```
function openInSameWindow(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default link behavior
    
    // Get the URL from the hyperlink
    var url = event.target.href;
    
    // Open the URL in a new tab within the same window
    window.open(url, '_self');
  }
```

I would be very grateful for any advice or suggestions on this. Many thanks for reading.

Comment: I believe this is a browser configuration issue